# How to pass value from html to typescript which included in Curly brackets

Tags: typescript, variables, ionic2

[image]

I am developing Hybrid chatting app using ionic 2 and I want to pass value from html to typescript on click event, but value is sync from firebase so it is in round brackets and html is not allow to set value in round brackets inside other round bracket.

> directchat.ts
>
> ```js
> import { Component, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
> import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular';
> import { MessagePage } from '../message/message';
> import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
> import { UserProvider } from '../../providers/user/user';
> import { AngularFire } from 'angularfire2';
> import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
> import { UsersPage } from '../users/users';
> import { ChatsProvider } from '../../providers/chats/chats';
>
> @Component({
>   selector: 'page-directchat',
>   templateUrl: 'directchat.html'
> })
> export class DirectchatPage {
>   userimg: any;
>   chats:Observable<any[]>;
>   constructor(public chatsProvider: ChatsProvider,
>       public userProvider: UserProvider, 
>       public af:AngularFire, 
>       public nav: NavController) {
>         let that = this;
>         this.chatsProvider.getChats()
>         .then(chats => {
>             that.chats = chats.map(users => {
>                 return users.map(user => {
>                     user.info = that.af.database.object(`/users/${user.$key}`);
>                     return user;
>                 });
>             });
>         });
>       }
>
>   openChat(key,name) {
>       this.userProvider.getUid()
>       .then(uid => {
>           let param = {uid: uid, interlocutor: key};
>           this.nav.push(MessagePage,param);
>       });   
>     }
>
> gotochats(){
>   this.nav.push(UsersPage)
> }
> goback(){
>   this.nav.pop()
>   } 
> }
> ```

Comment: Why don't you just pass the entire chat object to your click function and then grab the $key property within the function?

Comment: You are right and thanks for suggestion, But how can i get name's value in typescript. i mean how to write this "(chat.info | async)?.name" in typescript.